# Bootstrap DropDown enable under 1200px;

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I am building this site http://www.antpowerwebdevelopment.com in Wordpress / Bootstrap.

I am setting up the toggle dropdown at 1200px, however nothing is happening when I click the toggle button.

On a previous site I set up the menu in Wordpress as wp_list_pages then I built the pages and the menu appeared automatically and the toggle worked.

However this time I have built a main landing page with sections that the menu handcoded into header.php is then scrolling to each section.

So something is missing that I need some help to figure out to connect the dots to enable the dropdown to happen. I can style the menu as a dropdown list under 1200px, but I just need the magic js with the handcoded menu, Wordpress and Bootstrap to come together to enable the toggle to happen.

Ant

Comment: I could just write the menu responsively with CSS, but it'd be nice to have the toggle. Sorry JS isn't my strong point. But there might be a way to hook into the already existing functionality in Bootstrap.

Comment: OK call of the search party I fixed it with jQuery SlideToggle, hooked it into the already existing toogle icon and I'm doing the rest with HTML and CSS now.